# AsyncRestTemplate '#' sign encoding in query parameter

Tags: java, google-maps, spring-boot, encoding, asyncresttemplate

I am using [`AsyncRestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) to make an API call to Google Maps from a Springboot 1.5.2 service. Unfortunately, some of my search strings contain a pound/hashtag sign `#`
and are not getting encoded properly in my search parameters. I am using the [`exchange`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-java.util.Map-) method.

An example below for address `05406, VT, BURLINGTON, 309 College St #10`:

```
@Service
public class ExampleAsyncRestTemplate {

    private AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleAsyncRestTemplate() {
        this.asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
    }


    public ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<T>> getGeoCodedAddress() {
         String googleUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=05406, VT, BURLINGTON, 309 College St #10&key=some_key";

         Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
         uriVariables.put("address", "05406, VT, BURLINGTON, 309 College St #10");
         uriVariables.put("key", "some_key");

         return asyncRestTemplate.exchange(googleUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(), GoogleResponse.class, uriVariables);
    }
}
```

The resulting URL gets encoded as:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=05406,%20VT,%20BURLINGTON,%20309%20College%20St%20#10&key=some_key
```

Note that the `#` is still in the address parameter, when it should be encoded as `%23` as per the [`docs`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding).

Digging into the debugger, seems like the string after the `#` (`10&key=some_key`) is being taken as the [`fragment`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) of the URL. Hence why the `#` never gets encoded.

Has anybody been able to submit `#` signs in your query parameters using AsyncRestTemplate?

The only thing I've been able to come up with is replacing `#` with `number`, which actually works, but feels hacky/suboptimal.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `googleUrl` is a template where the encoded params get interpolated into. So you cannot provide the actual parameters as part of the url. You need to change the String into a template like this

```
final String googleUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={address}&key={key}";
```

This returns the correct encoding:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=05406,%20VT,%20BURLINGTON,%20309%20College%20St%20%2310&key=some_key
```